# Optimizing postrgeSQL query with joins and "ghost" references?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I made this query to get some data.

```
 select th.id, th.ticket_id, tp.name AS priority, ts.name AS state, owner_id AS player_id, g.id AS team_id, tt.name AS ticket_type
 from ticket_history th, ticket_priority tp, ticket_state ts, users, queue, ticket_type tt, groups g
 where th.priority_id = tp.id
 AND queue.id = g.id
 AND th.state_id = ts.id
 AND owner_id = users.id
 AND th.queue_id = queue.id
 AND th.type_id = tt.id
 AND th.id > $lastUpdateId
 ORDER BY th.id desc
```

It works just fine, however I got some complains that this query is slow (the 'complainer' didn't even bother to test it though)... but I decided to tweak it with some INNER JOINS - first question: that is the most efficient way to join tables and avoid repeating the main id (ticket_history in this case) right?

I refactored the query to look like this:

```
 select th.id, th.ticket_id, tp.name AS priority, ts.name AS state, owner_id AS player_id, g.id AS team_id, tt.name AS ticket_type
 FROM ticket_history, groups
 INNER JOIN queue ON queue.id = groups.id
 INNER JOIN ticket_priority ON ticket_priority.id = ticket_history.priority_id
 INNER JOIN ticket_state ON ticket_state.id = ticket_history.state_id
 INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ticket_history.owner_id
 INNER JOIN queue ON queue.id = ticket_history.queue_id
 INNER JOIN ticket_type ON ticket_type.id = ticket_history.type_id
 WHERE th.id > 7352616
 ORDER BY th.id desc
```

but now I get the error

```
    ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ticket_history"
LINE 4: ...NER JOIN ticket_priority ON (ticket_priority.id = ticket_his...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "ticket_history", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ticket_history"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "ticket_history", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Which brings me to my second question - what does this mean? I need to reference the ticket_history.priority_id ...

PS: My goal here is to get the data that's in ticket_history, but instead of having a priority_id I want the actual priority text and so on and so forth (except for the user and group where I actually want their id's instead of names). The trickiest part is where I have a queue id in ticket_history and from the queues table I need to extract the group_id which is the one I actually need.

EDIT: here's an example result from the first query

```
id;  ticket_id;  priority;  state;  user_id;  group_id;  type    
7376618; 203123; "4 Low"; "closed"; 385; 22; "Service Request"
7376617; 201341; "3 Medium"; "closed"; 100; 21; "Problem"
7376616; 201230; "1 SuperDuperHigh"; "closed"; 150; 10; "Service Request"
```

The query returns 7360 rows in 19067 seconds (give or take) from a localhost instance.
The original table "as is" contains the id's instead of the text/numbers. so it contains "type_id" instead of type. The group_id is the one that's fetches from correlation between two different tables. It goes ticket_history->queue->groups so it needs to relate those id's to find the group_id

EDIT2: The table diagram looks like this ([link](http://ftp.otrs.org/pub/otrs/doc/database-schema/otrs-2.4-database.png)) - look for the tables around ticket - it's the biggest one you can see

Comment: From the diagram it appears that you have no FKs from "ticket_history" to "queue", "owner" and "state". Is that correct? That is likely to incur a huge performance penalty when joining. Do you at least have an index on each of those columns?

Comment: @Patrick maybe that diagram I linked is a bit outdated. ticket_history contains a queue_id and that queue table it references contains a group_id that references the group table.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

> A JOIN clause combines two FROM items, which for convenience we will
>   refer to as "tables", though in reality they can be any type of FROM
>   item. Use parentheses if necessary to determine the order of nesting.
>   In the absence of parentheses, JOINs nest left-to-right. **In any case
>   JOIN binds more tightly than the commas separating FROM-list items.**

So the successive JOINs are relative to "groups", not "ticket_history". Flip the order of the tables to make it work:

```
SELECT th.id, th.ticket_id, tp.name AS priority, ts.name AS state, owner_id AS player_id,
       g.id AS team_id, tt.name AS ticket_type
FROM ticket_history th
JOIN ticket_priority tp ON tp.id = th.priority_id
JOIN ticket_state ts ON ts.id = th.state_id
-- JOIN users ON users.id = th.owner_id   NOT USED IN THE QUERY
JOIN queue ON queue.id = th.queue_id
JOIN ticket_type tt ON tt.id = th.type_id
JOIN groups g ON g.id = queue.id
WHERE th.id > 7352616
ORDER BY th.id DESC;
```

Note that `INNER` before `JOIN` is a noise word; you can safely omit it.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the user table join is used to restrict the records returned, even if there are no columns selected from the table? (i.e. if there are records in ticket_history with no corresponding users.id).

Comment: @mlinth I am pretty sure that the optimizer nukes the reference to the "users" table when building the query plan, would be interesting to test that. But even if not, this UoD smacks of lots of FKs and NOT NULL clauses.

Comment: In my case it's ok to omit rows from ticket_history if they don't have a user id. Which I don't think is happening. Those are the table sets of OTRS, the ticket management open source app, I think it's pretty solid structure doesn't allow that.

Comment: I'm trying to apply the same concept to another larger query (that serves the same purpose only to a different table - Ticket and relates with the above mentioned tables and a few more). However I'm running into the same mistake... what is the correct order? Do I join queues and tickets first or groups and queues?

EDIT : nevermind, I was switching groups and queues hence the confusion, all is good now. Thank you very much. The queries are slightly faster now.

Comment: There is no golden rule, you can order in both directions. Typically you start with the most "central" table and then work "outwards". Put the tables and their relationships in a quick sketch and you will see the most appropriate order. Just keep in mind that you can only join to tables mentioned before. And forget about comma-separated tables at all, it'll make your SQL easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't reference ticket_history there, because you've got a comma between ticket_history and groups, so ticket_history is not part of all those inner joins. If I've understood your table structure correctly[it would be easier if you posted table defs and sample data BTW] I think this will work:

```
select th.id, th.ticket_id, tp.name AS priority, ts.name AS state, owner_id AS player_id, g.id AS team_id, tt.name AS ticket_type
 FROM  groups
 INNER JOIN queue ON queue.id = groups.id
 -- include ticket_history with a join statement
INNER JOIN ticket_history ON queue.id = ticket_history.queue_id
     INNER JOIN ticket_priority ON ticket_priority.id = 
ticket_history.priority_id
 INNER JOIN ticket_state ON ticket_state.id = ticket_history.state_id
 INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ticket_history.owner_id

 INNER JOIN ticket_type ON ticket_type.id = ticket_history.type_id
 WHERE th.id > 7352616
 ORDER BY th.id desc
```

Comment: I edited the question to include sample data. The table diagram looks like this (http://ftp.otrs.org/pub/otrs/doc/database-schema/otrs-2.4-database.png) - look for the tables around ticket - it's the biggest one you can see.